# Стригти, обрізати, укорочувати

Tags: синоніми, дієслова

СУМ-11

> [Стригти](http://sum.in.ua/s/stryghty) 1. перех. і без додатка. Ножицями, машинкою і т. ін.
>   зрізувати, підрізувати (волосся, шерсть і т. ін.). //  Зрізувати або
>   підрізувати кому-небудь чи на чомусь волосся, шерсть і т. ін.  // 
>   Підрізувати волосся яким-небудь способом, за якоюсь модою, за якимсь
>   зразком і т. ін.  //  Підрізувати, укорочувати (листя, гілки, траву і
>   т. ін.). //  Підрізувати, укорочувати гілки, траву і т. ін. на дереві,
>   луці тощо.
>
> [Підрізувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidrizuvaty) 1. Різати, надрізати знизу, при основі або трохи, не
>   повністю. 2. Обрізаючи кінці, робити що-небудь коротшим, меншим.3.
>   Зрізувати верхівку рослини або частину її пагонів, щоб підсилити
>   плодоносіння, прискорити дозрівання.
>
> [Укорочувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/ukorochuvaty) 1. Робити що-небудь коротшим, меншим за довжиною./ 
>   Робити коротшим, меншим за довжиною, ніж звичайно, ніж потрібно.

З визначень слова стригти, роблю висновок, що можуть бути частковими. Проте в [словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B8#%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B20) інформаціїї, яка підтвердилаю мої припущення не знайшла. 
Чи можуть ці три слова бути синонімами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ***Укорочувати*** означає «зменшувати **довжину** чогось» («робити щось коротшим»). При цьому спосіб виконання цієї діє не фіксується. Адже є різні способи обробки матеріалів: різанням, рубкою, шліфуванням. І в залежності від того, довжину чого ми зменшуємо, множина способів може різнитися: іноді можна вкоротити від'єднянням додаткових деталей, налаштуванням телескопічної конструкції; шлях можна вкоротити, йдучи навпростець; вік можна вкоротити, ігноруючи правила безпеки.

  Приклад: [image: сокира + колода = укоротшена колода] — це укорочування, але не підрізування чи стриження.
- ***Підрізувати*** означає «**ріжучи**, робити **трішки** меншим». При цьому не фіксується, в якому саме напрямі і яку саме частину ми зменшуємо. Коротко кажучи, підрізаючи, ми необов'язково зменшуємо саме довжину. Хоча в контексті певних об'єктів *підрізування* може мати вужче значення (наприклад, під *підрізуванням рослини* мається на увазі підрізування саме верхівки або пагонів, а не, наприклад, кореня чи плодів), але в загальному випадку це будь-яке (невеличке) зменшення об'єму чогось різанням.

  Приклад: [image: ніж + колода = колода тієї ж довжини, але з виїмкою] — це підрізування, але не укорочування чи стриження.
- ***Стригти*** зазвичай застосовують до **підрізання (чи відрізання) багатьох (чи декількох) однотипних елементів**: волосин, нігтів, листків, тонких гілок тощо.

  Приклад: [image: ножиці + колода з листям = колода без листя] — це стриження (й, можливо, підрізування), але не укорочування.

<sub>Щодо авторського права: у цій відповіді застосовані модифікації таких зображень, що розповсюджуються під ліцензією CC: Wood by Jugalbandi from the Noun Project, Axe by Nociconist from the Noun Project, Knife by Dávid Gladiš from the Noun Project, Scissors by kareemov from the Noun Project.</sub>